# MVC Controller receives DateTime parsed as different culture from CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, culture

I have an ajax call sending data from a datepicker as a short date to my controller's method. Inside my controller I want to use the date to filter entries in a table, and return the whole thing along with the date.

My app's culture is french (`fr-FR`)

Let's use `June 12th 2015` for our examples.

I encountered several problems:

The jQuery datepicker is defaulted to have `dateFormat: "DD d MM yy"`, so when I pick June 12th in the date picker, the field shows "vendredi 12 juin 2015" and the JS sends `"vendredi+12+juin+2015"` as my DateTime field, which yields `null` inside the controller's method.

I decided to fix that by re-specifying the `dateFormat` to be `"dd/mm/yy"` which takes less screen space anyway.
Now, when I pick june 12th, the fields holds (and the JS sends) `"12/06/2015"` which yields `{06/12/2015 00:00:00}` in the controller's method *with 12 as the month and 06 as the day*. I checked my `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to see it is `{fr-FR}`, so I don't understand why `"12/06/2015"` is parsed as December 6th.

I implemented `IAuthorizationFilter` in my controller to see in `OnAuthorization` what were the CurrentThread's culture:
Both `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` are `{fr-FR}`

I tried turning it around, and set the date picker format to `mm/dd/yyyy` which (in)correctly translates June 12th to `"06/12/2015"` which yields `{12/06/2015 00:00:00}` in the controller's method. This could work but then when my date is reinserted into the page, it's "12/06/2015" which is correct but interpreted by datepicker as December 12th because of the date format.

I also tried sending the value with `$('#date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy "}).val()` and leave the datepicker format on the first call as `"dd/mm/yy"`, but this still gives me the value formatted as `"dd/mm/yy"`

I had to parse and then format the date like this:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", $('#date').val()))
```

In order to "reverse" the month and the day to *trick* the server into parsing it as June 12th.

Additionnal info: I have no `<globalization ...>` in my Web.config nor do I have any custom model binder.

I could maybe try to have a SSCCE if you need it but it looks like it's hard to shrink down...

**TL;DR**: I have `CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = {fr-FR}` displayed when I break on the first line inside my controller's method, yet my DateTime sent as `"12/06/2015"` (June 12th) in the request is parsed as `"06/12/2015"` (December 6th) before being passed to my controller's method.

---

Why does my `CurrentCulture` does not seem to be taken into account when the server is parsing the date?

Comment: Duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566747/datetime-parse-not-reversing-month-and-day-based-on-thread-culture

Comment: Maybe related but i'm not calling DateTime.Parse myself so in no way it's a duplicate. I need an answer based on MVC automated model binding which is not doing its job properly

Comment: Can you tell what is your `CurrentUICulture` value?

Comment: Probably `fr-FR` culture has `dd/MM/yyyy` as a standard date and time format, not `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: @SonerGönül that's the thing, `dd/MM/yyyy` is supposed to parse `"12/06/2015"` as June 12th, but it parses it as December 6th.

Comment: @Eregrith How do you parse it exactly? With the Javascript code in your question or C#? I'm not too much familiar with JS.

Comment: @SonerGönül No, the MVC model binding parses it, as I said in my question

Comment: @Kamo `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is `{fr-FR}` as well in `OnAuthorization`. `CurrentUICulture` is `{fr-FR}` as well at this state.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure your culture is set before the model binding occurs. If you check your `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` setting inside your controllers action than it's posiible that this was set after the date was parsed by your model binder.

You can check this by implementing IAuthorizationFilter.

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is `{fr-FR}` as well in `OnAuthorization`. `CurrentUICulture` is `{fr-FR}` as well at this state.